# How can I made my code thread safe or is it thread safe as is?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I read on a previous stack overflow post the following: "If your static method does not change any member variables, and does not call mutating methods on its parameters, it is re-entrant, and is, therefore, thread-safe" to which I believe my code adhere to but I'm just seeking some confirmation.  Below is my code.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    private static Logger _log = LogManager.GetLogger("PortalLog");
    public static void NLoglogger(Exception ex, string loginId)
   {
        if (ex.InnerException == null)
        {
            LogEventInfo errorEvent = new LogEventInfo(LogLevel.Error, "PortalLog", ex.Message);
            errorEvent.Properties["loginid"] = loginId ;
            _log.Log(errorEvent);
        }
        else
        {
            LogEventInfo errorEvent = new LogEventInfo(LogLevel.Error, "PortalLog", ex.Message + "Inner Message: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
            errorEvent.Properties["loginid"] = loginId;
            _log.Log(errorEvent);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Well, your code uses some `Logger` class so you would need to know whether everything that happens there is thread-safe

Comment: Yes, my logger which is NLog is thread-safe.

Comment: Your code is thread safe, but the logger might not be. You have no control over it, but that could be described in its documentation. One thing I should do is make the logger variable readonly. `private static readonly Logger _log = LogManager.GetLogger("PortalLog");`